# FOSUserBundle: How reorganize the fields?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm beginner with Symfony and I trying to implement FOSUserBundle.

I follow the guide http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html in order to add my own fields. I have the following snippet:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->remove('username')
    ->add('lastname')
    ->add('firstname')
    ->add('birthday', DateType::class);
}
```

When I test this code, I have the following order for registration fields:

- Email
- Password
- Password Confirm
- **Lastname**
- **Firstname**
- **Birthday**

But I would like to change the order of fields like:

- **Lastname**
- **Firstname**
- **Birthday**
- Email
- Password
- Password Confirm

Did you have a solution to resolve my problem please?
Thank you,
Clem

Comment: Override the twig template and output the fields in whatever order you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render your form field by field like this:

```
{{ form_label(form.username) }}
{{ form_widget(form.username) }}
{{ form_errors(form.username) }}

{{ form_label(form.email) }}
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
{{ form_errors(form.email) }}

{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}

{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
```

Just add your new created fields to the template in the order you want.

Check out this also https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1077

Comment: Thank you, It's now operational :)